# How can I change my Button's text dynamically based on my Gridview Row click?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I am using ASP.NET C#. I have a Gridview (example shown below [gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkL1F.png)) and a Button. As I click on the rows of the gridview, my button’s text needs to change depending on the info of the gridview.

For example: If I click on the first row, the text of my Button should be Alpha (Operation name). If I click on the third row, it should have Charlie on it and so on. The user could click any row any number of times and the button should change on every new click.

I have learnt the use of onRowDataBound and SelectedIndexChanged event of the gridview to play around with the value in the gridview. I was able to print out each row of the gridview using labels.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView2, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
                e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row. ";
            }
        }

        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowIndex == GridView1.SelectedIndex)
                {
                    row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A1DCF2");
                    row.ToolTip = string.Empty;
                    String ID;
                    alertNo = row.Cells[0].Text;
                    String Operation;
                    Operation = row.Cells[1].Text;
                    String Month;
                    Month = row.Cells[2].Text
                }
                else
                {
                    row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
                    row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row";
                }
            }

        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label2.Visible = true;
        Label3.Visible = true;

        }
```

However I do not understand how I can change the text of a button using this method.

Any help with would be greatly appreciated (Javascript/ JQuery/C#). Please let me know if the question is unclear in anyway.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do you have an Id on the button you can use as a reference? Are you looking to do this through Javascript? If so, you can find the element by Id and manipulate the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your C# code you can try the following:

```
String Operation;
Operation = row.Cells[1].Text;
Button1.Text = Operation; // Add this line just after you get the Operation value
```

You can do it better/faster with Javascript/jQuery, but since you already have most part using C#.

**EDIT 1**: Here's a working pure jQuery example https://jsfiddle.net/gy31Lufr/2/.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML should have an id attribute associated with every button , something like this ;

````
<button id="button2" name="Click button two!" type="button" > Click button two! </button>
...
<button id="buttonN" name="Click button N!" type="button" > Click button N! </button> ```

Now in the JQuery code , you can do a DOM traversal ,example;
$("#button1").click(function(){
  this.attr("name","Alpha (Operation name)");
});

$("#button2").click(function(){
  this.attr("name","Charlie on it");
});

This is a solution based on HTML and Jquery , the key ingredient is for every button to have an unique ID.
````